# Path components of Wedge Sum

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

I couldn't find this anywhere else, so I decided to post it here.

I suspect that the wedge sum $⋁X_α$ of pointed spaces $X_α$ has as path components all components of the topological sum $\oplus X_α$ not containing any base point, plus a single component which is the wedge of all components containing the base points.
In particular, if we have $n$ spaces with $m$ components, the wedge will have $m-n+1$ components.

This should follow from

> **Theorem:** If $p$ is a path in $(X,x_0)=\bigvee_α(X_α,x_α)$ between distinct $X_α$ and $X_β$, then $p(0)$ must lie in the path component of $x_α$.
>   **Proof:** *Case 1:* Assume $m=\min\{s\in I\mid p(s)\notin X_α\}$. In that case, we can assume that $m=1$ and $p(1)\in X_β$, so $p([0,1))\subseteq X_α$. If we define $$q(s)=\begin{cases}p(s), & s<1\\
> x_0, & s=1\end{cases}$$
>   we only need to check continuity of $q$ at $1$. Let $U$ be an open neighbourhood of $x_0$ in the subspace $X_α$ of $X$. Then the neighbourhood $U\vee\bigvee_{\gamma\neα} X_\gamma$ of $p(1)$ contains the image of some $(1-\delta,1]$ under $p$ since that path is continuous. Thus $p((1-\delta,1))=q((1-\delta,1))⊆U$. Hence $q$ is a path in $X_α$ from $p(0)$ to $x_α$.
>   *Case 2:* Assume $m=\max\{s\in I\mid p([0,s])⊆X_α\}$. Then $p(m)$ is in the closure of $⋁_{γ≠α}X_γ$, so it must be in the closure of $\{x_α\}$. There is thus a path 
>   $q:I→\{p(m),x_α\}$ which we can glue to $p|_{[0,m]}$ to get a path within $X_α$ from $p(0)$ to $x_α$.

From this is follows that points in different summands of the wedge can be joined only if they are both in their respective path components containing the base points.

Do you see any flaws? Or do you know if the proof for this fact can be found in literature?

Thanks.

Comment: This can also be expressed as: The functor $\pi_0$ preserves coproducts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**N.B.** This answer is flawed. The reasoning below shows that a path-component of $X$ is either the path-component of $x_0$ or the image of a path-component
of some $X_\alpha$. It does not follow immediately that the path-component of
$x_0$ is the union of the path-components of the $x_\alpha$. 
(It does follow if $\{x_0\}$ is closed.)

---

I don't see anything wrong in your proof, but maybe I can put a different
spin on it. The following line of reasoning seems more intuitive to me.

1. Let $q$ be the quotient map taking the disjoint union to the wedge sum. 
   The restriction of $q$ to $q^{-1}(X \setminus \overline{\{x_0\}})$ is a homeomorphic
   embedding. (it's injective, continuous and open) It follows that any path
   not passing through $\overline{\{x_0\}}$ is already a path in the disjoint
   union.
2. The closure of a point in any topological space is path-connected.

The result you want then seems obvious.

Comment: Thanks for checking my proof. I'm still not convinced about your reasoning, though. This implies that a path between different $X_α$ must meet the closure of $x_0$ in the wedge, so there is a path to $x_0$ in $⋁X_α.$ But what I'm aiming at is that this path must lie in a single $X_α$.

Comment: I did not fully appreciate the subtlety of your case 1. Now that I have looked at it more closely, your proof still looks good, and I don't think that it can be done much simpler.